# Remainder term in taylor series expansion of maximum likelihood estimator

Tags: maximum-likelihood, estimators, taylor-series

I'm trying to understand the proof for the asymptotic normality of the MLE estimator. The proof I saw in class begins with the Taylor series expansion around the true value of $\theta$:

$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\log f(x_i,\hat{\theta}) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\log f(x_i,\hat{\theta}) + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2\theta}\log f(x_i,\hat{\theta})(\hat{\theta}-\theta_0) +o_p(|\hat{\theta}-\theta_0|^2) \right]
$$

At first I thought the square on the remainder term could be a mistake (that is, that the remainder is $o_p(|\hat{\theta}-\theta|)$). But now I've seen a few other proofs that also have the square in there. Could I get some help understanding why?

Comment: Hello. Welcome to CV. Please cite your sources as that would help to get better context.

Comment: Hi! These were slides from my class but I saw the same remainder term in the top rates answer on this post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110394/taylors-expansion-on-log-likelihood

Comment: Check  Stéphane Laurent's reply [there](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110394/taylors-expansion-on-log-likelihood#comment1202401_110679).